# How to search in an output generated by a http request

Tags: php, javascript, http, session

I am using [THIS](http://www.d-centralize.nl/pro6pp/examples/range) api for searching postcodes in a range around it.
it generates an automatic output when I type in a postcode (1234) for example.
it's using jquery autocomplete for that.

Now is my question.
How can I save that output in a session and search within that session to match any of the postcodes I have in my companydatabase?

my code looks like this:

my form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="pro6pp_range">
    <input type="text" class="postcode" placeholder="Postcode (1234)" maxlength="4">
      <select class="range">
        <option value="5" selected="selected">5 km</option>
        <option value="10">10 km</option>
        <option value="15">15 km</option>
        <option value="20">20 km</option>
        <option value="25">25 km</option>
      </select>
      <br/><br/>
    <span class="message"></span>
    <div class="output"></div>
    <br/>
</form>
```

my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pro6pp_auth_key = "MY_AUTH_KEY";
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pro6pp_range").applyRange({ 'assemble_func': assemble_one });
    function assemble_one(result) {
        distance_km = Math.round(result.distance / 1000);
        return "Afstand tot " + result.nl_fourpp + " is " + 
        distance_km + " km vanaf uw locatie.<br />";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Range.js:

```
// Create closure to keep namespace clean and hide implementation.
(function($) {
    $.fn.applyRange = function(options) {
        var instance = this;

        function getConfig(field, default_value) {
            if (typeof options === 'undefined' ||
                typeof options[field] === 'undefined') {
                return default_value;
            } else {
                // Developer chose to specify form field manually.
                return options[field];
            }
        }

        instance.postcode = getConfig('postcode', instance.find('.postcode'));
        instance.range = getConfig('range', instance.find('.range'));  
        instance.message = getConfig('message', instance.find('.message'));
        instance.spinner = getConfig('spinner', instance.find('.spinner'));
        instance.output = getConfig('output', instance.find('.output'));

        instance.distance = getConfig('distance', instance.find('.distance'));
        instance.lat = getConfig('lat', instance.find('.lat'));
        instance.lng = getConfig('lng', instance.find('.lng'));
        instance.nl_fourpp = getConfig('nl_fourpp', instance.find('.nl_fourpp'));

        instance.assemble_func = getConfig('assemble_func', assemble_one);

        instance.postcode.keyup(function() {
            range(instance);
        }); 
    };

    var pro6pp_cache = {};
    function pro6pp_cached_get(obj, url, params, callback) {
        var key = url + $.param(params);
        if (pro6pp_cache.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
                callback(obj, pro6pp_cache[key]);
            }
        } else {
            $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", params, function(data) {
                pro6pp_cache[key] = data;
                if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
                    callback(obj, data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function getApiBaseUrl() {
        // Use HTTPS API if website itself is also secure.
        // Otherwise, some browsers might complain about insecure content.
        if ("https:" === document.location.protocol) {
            return 'https://pro6pp.appspot.com/v1';
        } else {
            return 'http://api.pro6pp.nl/v1';
        }
    }

    function range(obj) {
        obj.message.hide().empty();
        var postcode = obj.postcode.val();
        var range = obj.range.val();
        // Trigger on '5408'
        var nl_fourpp_regex = /[0-9]{4,4}\s?/;
        if (nl_fourpp_regex.test(postcode)) {
            var url = getApiBaseUrl() + "/range";
            var params = new Object();
            params.auth_key = pro6pp_auth_key;
            params.per_page = 100;
            params.nl_fourpp = postcode;
            // User puts in range in kilometers, API uses meters.
            range = parseInt(range, 10) * 1000;
            params.range = range;
            pro6pp_cached_get(obj, url, params, fillin);
        }
    }

    function assemble_one(result) {
        distance_km = Math.round(result.distance / 1000);
        return "Afstand tot " + result.nl_fourpp + " is " + distance_km + " km<br />";
    }

    function fillin(obj, json) {
        if (json.status == 'ok') {
            obj.output.empty();

            var postcode = obj.postcode.val();
            $.each(json.results, function(i, result) {
                if (result.nl_fourpp === postcode) {
                    return true;
                }
                obj.output.append(obj.assemble_func(result)).show();
            });
            if (json.results.length > 1) {          
                obj.distance.val(json.results[1].distance);
                obj.nl_fourpp.val(json.results[1].nl_fourpp);
                obj.lat.val(json.results[1].lat);
                obj.lng.val(json.results[1].lng);
            } else {
                translated_message = 'Geen resultaten gevonden';
                obj.message.html(translated_message).show();
            }
        } else {
            var translated_message = json.error.message;
            if (json.error.message == 'nl_fourpp niet gevonden') {
                translated_message = 'Onbekende postcode';
            } else if (json.error.message == 'Invalid nl_fourpp format') {
                    translated_message = 'Ongeldig postcode formaat';
            } else if (json.error.message == 'invalid target_nl_fourpps format') {
                translated_message = 'Ongeldig target_nl_fourpps formaat';
            }

            obj.message.html(translated_message).show();
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I hope someone knows how to save an output from a request to a session/cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well what you want, I think when you function is done, you have to call an ajax function to send out put to a php script on the server, that will save that output in a session and you can do any processing you want from there.

```
function send_data_to_server(output)
{
    var postal_code=$('.postcode').val();
    var url = 'http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/script.php?output='+output+'&postal_code='+postal_code;

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        success : function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and just before your return "Afstand tot " + result.nl_fourpp + " is " +distance_km + " km vanaf uw locatie.
";

put this line of code:

```
  send_data_to_server(result.nl_fourpp);
```

script.php

```
<?php 
     session_start();
     $output=$_GET['output'];
     $_SESSION['postal'][]=$output;
     echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: I am using the api. so my url is in range.js the file who loads it from the api site. how to do it that way?

Comment: what do you mean, what file you're talking about? if you're worried about the path to php file, then use url, as long as it is on the same domain it will work. var url="http://your_domain.com/script.php?output="+output; there is an http:// but it gets lost when SO automatically link the url

Comment: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/search here i use the api from pro6pp. when i type in a postcode it autocompletes and shows me the postcodes within a radius. i just want to save that output. or actually use that to search in my factories table.

Comment: ok so if you want to send your data from javascript to a php script on your website you use the function I gave you up there you replace var url='path/to/script.php?output='+output; by var url='http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/script.php?output='+output; and you put that script in your root directory

Comment: so what do i have to code in that script.php? did you see the working example on the link i gave?

Comment: yes I saw, but I can't understand a word :P in script.php your output will be in $_GET['output'] then you do whatever you want with it. if you want to send like 10 post codes, you can json encode them then they'll be sent to the php script as json string, then in the php you json_decode the results to get an array

Comment: allright will look at it. first just look at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/search and type '9101' in the first input field. leave the radius as it is. you can see it shows some results. can I save those results in a session with your script?

Comment: yes I tried 9101 I got like 10 results, my function will let you send these to your server, then from there you have to save them in a session. 5 mins I'll update the code to show you how to json encode the results in javascript then how to json decode them in php

Comment: the problem is that I can see that assemble_one is treating one result I can't see where all the results are, so I'll assume that you have all the results in an array.

Comment: it's an database full of postcodes in google cloud. I can't see where it's coming from. i can post my range.js file where all the configuration for the script are done. i post it above.

Comment: updated the code it just alerts the print_r of php at the moment, it will show you that the data arrived to php then you do with it what you want. But first you have to find a workaround to store your postal codes in a js array to be able to send that array to send_data_to_server function

Comment: yes that's my problem :). i just need to grap and somehow save the outpot so i can search with those values.

Comment: what you can do is you can send them 1 by 1 to the server. give me 5 more mins

Comment: check what happens now, let me know if you understand or if you need more help.

Comment: i get no alert and nothing is sent

Comment: oh i get an alert. for each result. but nothing in script.php

Comment: my mistake, you were getting an empty alert, I edited the code retry now, additionally upload a script2.php in script2.php just write <?php print_r($_SESSION);?> after trying if everything works fine when you visit your_url/script2.php you should see the postal codes in the session variable postal. Hope I am clear.

Comment: i will try this tommorrow. don't have time now.

Comment: when i do a print_r($_SESSION) in script.php it gives me Array ( [postal] => Array ( [0] => ) ) and without that the page is empty. what is wrong? i get an alert.

Comment: edited the code we forgot to start a session on script.php that's it when you're not concentrated.

Comment: yeah i thought of something like that. i tried it in the searchpage but it did not work. now it does i guess.

Comment: yes. it is saving the output to the session :) now i just need to figure out how to use those to search. thanks!

Comment: 1 question. how can I overwrite the session when i type in a new postcode?

Comment: ok well when your done testing remove alert(data); to stop the popups and you can process your data in script.php

Comment: save the postal code searched in a session too, then every time test if the postal code changed if yes unset($_SESSION['postal']);

Comment: how could i do that the best way? i'm a bit stuck

Comment: I updated the code, this way you'll be sending the searched post code each time to script.php you will have it as $_GET['postal_code'], this is not the best solution but can't do better as I don't see/have access to the code.

Comment: what do you need? i have the code above in the OP. but i will try this.

Comment: do i need to do something like if(isset($_GET['postal_code']{ unset($_SESSION['postal']? because it's still not overwriting.

Comment: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/script.php and http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/search?# just look at it.

Comment: you can try it yourself. for a clear view i just deleted the session. now you can add a new one.

Comment: is there anywhere else we can talk this is getting too long! I can see all the found postal codes stored in a session... that's where we already arrived.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29906/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-codebird)